# How to build and serve a web application / back end server with limited access?

Tags: build

In a attempt to both help my wife organizing her work and study some javascript I've set up a frontend using ReactJS and some basic server with NodeJS and PostgreSQL. The idea is pretty simple: 2-3 web pages with some form to be filled and saved through some backend magic ( her sales, clients and addresses and some other infos ) and it's currently working fine, despite some few bugs I'm currently working on.
My main concern now is where to host it: she works in an office. How should I make it accesible to and only to her? I have no experience in built applications, currently a hobbist studying javascript =D

Currently on my own pc I serve it with "nodemon index.js" and "yarn dev" and voilá

Comment: Its no longer a programming question, its a web page-serving question.  Perhaps it should be on Webmasters site